# How do you group dates by day in solr?

Tags: sql, date, solr, lucene, grouping

What is the best way to group dates by day or month in solr queries ?
For example if I have the date in the following format: `20140108180854746` (actually the format doesn't matter all that much here, might as well be in a normal format), is there an easy way to just group by its days or months.
Someone suggested keeping a field just for the days that it will group by and the other solution I saw was something in the lines of

```
&group=true&group.func=rint(div(ms(date_dt),mul(24,mul(60,mul(60,1000)))))
```

which isn't exactly user friendly but it will do the trick I guess. 
Any general advice about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are in-built faceting methods to accomplish this. You can use the "facet.date.gap" param to achieve this. Take a look at the following example.

```
q=solr&facet=true
&facet.date=j_createddate
&facet.date.gap=+1DAY,+2DAY,+3DAY,+10DAY
```

Here, we define date faceting for j_createddate, a date field. Then we create compartments for the gaps 1 days, 2 days, 3 days and 10 days

Refer http://solr.pl/en/2010/08/23/the-scope-of-solr-faceting/ & http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.date.gap

Comment: facet.date is deprecated in Solr 3.1 better use facet.range